# How can I fix a memory error in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, jupyter-notebook

I am doing a NLP project in jupyter notebook with a dataset involving 160000 rows. Upon running the given code I am getting a memory error.

```
messages = list(zip(processed, Y))

# defined a seed for reproducibility
seed = 1
np.random.seed = seed
np.random.shuffle(messages)

# calling find_features function for each comments
featuresets = [(find_features(text), label) for (text, label) in messages]
```

The error showing is -

```
<ipython-input-18-faca481e94f7> in find_features(message)
      3     features = {}
      4     for word in word_features:
----> 5         features[word] = (word in words)
      6 
      7     return features

MemoryError:
```

Is there any way this can be fixed.
I am running a windows 64bit 4gb RAM core i5 8th Gen Laptop.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure it will completely solve your problem but you seem to create a dictionary with boolean values that store the result of the search of a word in a list/set/whatever.

If only a few words are in the list, it still creates a huge dictionary with a lot of `False` values, when you just need `True` values (unless you need to know which values have been tested)

I would replace:

```
features = {}
for word in word_features:
   features[word] = (word in words)
```

with

```
features = set()
for word in word_features:
    if word in words:
        features.add(word)
```

or set comprehension:

```
features = {word for word in word_features if word in words}
```

Now to test if `word` exists in `features` just do `if word in features:`

Creating a `set` containing only the matching word eliminates the entries where the test is `False` and it also eliminates the *value*, keeping only the keys where the word belongs.

Comment: Heck, I didn't even know that a *set* comprehension exists...! :)